# How to process PDO object in multiple for loops

Tags: php, mysql, html, pdo

Im trying to create a dynamic web page but have an issue with a for loop. In my html code I have a div called section group which can hold 4 columns at once. One product is shown in one column. In my database I have 13 products that means I want 13 columns to be dynamically generated. So to hold 13 columns 4 section group divs should also generated. The code is below.

```
    <div class="menu_list">
             <div class="section group">

                <?php foreach($products as $product): ?>

                    <div class="col_1_of_4 span_1_of_4">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="item_name"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <img src="images/<?php echo $product['image']; ?>" alt="" />
                <div class="button" align="center"><span><a href="buy.php">Buy Now</a></span></div>
                </div>


                <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>          
      </div>
```

Here is the php code.Im using PDO.

```
    $products = $db->prepare("
                SELECT *
                FROM products
                ");

    $products->execute();

    $products = $products->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

What I want to happen is when 4 objects get pulled out of the database a new section group should be generated. So my final desire is this.

```
    <div class="menu_list">
             <div class="section group">


                    <div class="col_1_of_4 span_1_of_4">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="item_name"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <img src="images/<?php echo $product['image']; ?>" alt="" />
                <div class="button" align="center"><span><a href="buy.php">Buy Now</a></span></div>
                </div>

    <div class="col_1_of_4 span_1_of_4">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="item_name"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <img src="images/<?php echo $product['image']; ?>" alt="" />
                <div class="button" align="center"><span><a href="buy.php">Buy Now</a></span></div>
                </div>

    <div class="col_1_of_4 span_1_of_4">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="item_name"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <img src="images/<?php echo $product['image']; ?>" alt="" />
                <div class="button" align="center"><span><a href="buy.php">Buy Now</a></span></div>
                </div>

    <div class="col_1_of_4 span_1_of_4">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="item_name"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <img src="images/<?php echo $product['image']; ?>" alt="" />
                <div class="button" align="center"><span><a href="buy.php">Buy Now</a></span></div>
                </div>

        </div>

    <div class="section group">


                    <div class="col_1_of_4 span_1_of_4">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="item_name"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <img src="images/<?php echo $product['image']; ?>" alt="" />
                <div class="button" align="center"><span><a href="buy.php">Buy Now</a></span></div>
                </div>

    <div class="col_1_of_4 span_1_of_4">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="item_name"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <img src="images/<?php echo $product['image']; ?>" alt="" />
                <div class="button" align="center"><span><a href="buy.php">Buy Now</a></span></div>
                </div>

    <div class="col_1_of_4 span_1_of_4">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="item_name"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <img src="images/<?php echo $product['image']; ?>" alt="" />
                <div class="button" align="center"><span><a href="buy.php">Buy Now</a></span></div>
                </div>

    <div class="col_1_of_4 span_1_of_4">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="item_name"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <img src="images/<?php echo $product['image']; ?>" alt="" />
                <div class="button" align="center"><span><a href="buy.php">Buy Now</a></span></div>
                </div>

        </div>          
      </div>
```

I apologize if the code is too excessive. Ive tried so many for loops variations to no avail. Please help me if possible. Thank you all.

Comment: I don't know why you're using `prepare()`, you've nothing TO prepare http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements - Just use `query()`. Unless that's all you have and you're asking us to fill in the blanks(?).

Comment: I had conditions in there just posted simplified one to show that Im going with PDO

Comment: so do you want 4 times of 13 colunns? or 13 rows of 4 columns?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't 100% get your goal.

But it seems that you mean something like:

```
<div class="menu_list">
    <div class="section group">

        <?php
            $idx=0;
            foreach($products as $product) { 
                $idx++;

                if ($idx % 4 == 1 && $idx>1 ) {
                    echo '</div><div class="section group">';
                }
        ?>

                <div class="col_1_of_4 span_1_of_4">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="item_name"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <img src="images/<?php echo $product['image']; ?>" alt="" />
                <div class="button" align="center"><span><a href="buy.php">Buy Now</a></span></div>
                </div>

        <?php 
            } ?>
    </div>          
</div>
```